# Checkboxlist C# - Need to check items inside, by passing parameters

Tags: c#, methods, checklistbox

I have a CheckBoxList and check boxes with labels not fix, it would change.

I would like to pass multiple Strings in a method, which will read string and match with label names of checkboxes inside list, then check if matches.

e.g.
List contain following check boxes.

```
Chk1
Chk3
Chk5
Chk7
```

Method:  Public void Method(str Stringstobeentered)

```
User can pass (chk1;chk7;chk3), then 3 check boxes will get selected
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want but you should look at `params`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(v=vs.71).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
public void SelectList(string[] selectedText){

  foreach(string item in selectedText){
     CheckBoxList1.Items.FindByText(item).Selected = true;
     // User FindByValue in case of to find the item via value.
  }

}
```

Call function like this :

```
SelectedList(new[]{ "text1", "text2" });
```

Or if you want it like dynamic n-array use params than method prototype would be

```
public void SelectList(params string[] selectedText)
```

and calling procedure would be

```
SelectedList("text1", "text2");
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Can i pass multiple string parameters in method, which will read and match with check boxes labels.

Comment: @Santii20, I have updated my answer. Its a demo in which i take two values, but you can pass more as per the requirement.

Comment: Thanks Kundan, let me try this out

Comment: I dont find "FindByText(item)"

Comment: @Santii20, are you not getting FindByText() method?

Comment: yes kundan, i am not getting checkedListBox1.Items.FindbyText

Comment: @Santii20, its strange. does it not coming in intellisense. If this so try to write that once and compile the code.

Comment: Not showing, i am using VS2010, may be some issue, let me try writing it

Comment: I just found, its not checkedlistbox, but on list box, check boxes were placed.

Comment: ohh @Santii20, then the solution would be different. Share the aspx mark up so i can provide you solution accordingly.

Comment: Its a List, inside which there are multiple check boxes (which can vary from env to env). I have to write a method where user has to pass parameter like public bool FillPublishersCheckBoxes(String EnteredPublishersName), where Parameter can look like "A;B;C", so if A,B,C named check boxes available then all 3 check boxes will get selected, else none.